# Chrome v32 drop down bottom item highlight issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, dropdownbox

I just upgraded to Chrome v32. (previously had v28) Now the  drop downs have a fade-in/fade-out animation but they have a weird issue.

- If the drop down has **more than 4 items**, you cannot highlight the bottom item. But you can select it if you click it.
- If you open-up a drop down whose bottom item is already selected, it opens up with the bottom item highlighted. But as soon as you hover the mouse over other items you can't highlight the bottom item again.

Is anybody seeing this issue? Is there a workaround I can apply to my website css to force chrome use the old drop down logic?

An example of this issue can be seen on chrome's own [bug tracker page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list). Just try the "Search" drop down.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. I'm sure it's well documented at this point. Expect a fix very quickly (surprised to see it's not already fixed, actually).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a known bug. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334227

Comment: This issue has been corrected with the latest version of the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link to the official bug report:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334227

Answer (score 0):

Same here.

And Chrome Bug Tracker is [there](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/36Nf3/

```
<select id="dateRangeString" name="dateRangeString" class="body11" style="width:165px" tabindex="10"><option value="" selected="selected">Please select one</option><option value="01/20/2014 - 01/26/2014">01/20/2014 - 01/26/2014</option><option value="01/13/2014 - 01/19/2014">01/13/2014 - 01/19/2014</option><option value="01/06/2014 - 01/12/2014">01/06/2014 - 01/12/2014</option><option value="12/30/2013 - 01/05/2014">12/30/2013 - 01/05/2014</option><option value="12/23/2013 - 12/29/2013">12/23/2013 - 12/29/2013</option><option value="12/16/2013 - 12/22/2013">12/16/2013 - 12/22/2013</option></select>
```

Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m